# BIC difference for model selection when models have different (and correlated) predictors

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity, model-comparison, bic, nested-models

I have a binomial dependent variable Y and two main IVs: A is categorical (5 non ordered levels) and B is continuous.
A and B are collinear (I tested the effect of A on B with a linear model, and it turned out to be significant). Moreover, I fitted 3 logistic mixed-effects models (using *glmer* from *lme4*):

1) Y ~ A

2) Y ~ B

3) Y ~ A + B

Both predictors in *model 1* and *model 2* were significant, however in *model 3* the effect of B was no longer significant (the estimated *β*s changed from -0.38 (sd=0.02) in model 2 to -0.02 (sd=0.02) in model 3). I think that this is a consequence of the collinearity between A and B, even if all the VIFs in model 3 are <2.

Since my hypothesis is that A is a better predictor of Y than B, I would like to know if I can prove this by using the BIC difference between model 1 and model 2 (in this case, ΔBIC = 574, suggesting that model A is much better than model B). 
I know that the BIC difference allows the comparison between non-nested models, but I'm not sure I can apply it to my case.

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: I suggest you do not try to argue one model is better than another based on BIC differences. Bootstrap you model and generate ROC curves or some other kind of summary statistic or graphic you feel comfortable with and show that one model is better than the other. Hypothesis testing for information criteria is a dubious game; avoid it unless you are very well-versed on the field and you are willing to back it with case-specific asymptotic results.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. (1) I'm not very familiar with bootstrapping techniques, could you recommend any library/function for bootstrapping? (2) Do you believe collinearity between A and B is an issue here, despite the good VIFs?

Comment: (1) In R the library `boot` is the first place to check, look at the book they cite. (2) As you compare against models 1 and 2 collinearity should not be a significant issue because variables `A` and `B` are never in the same model.

Comment: Finding that the slope coefficient is statistically significant in a regression of A on B does not mean A and B are collinear. VIF should be more useful than statistical significance of slope coefficient. Regarding comparing non-nested models, maybe you could do this: build an encompassing model with both A and B, then test whether A is statistically significant and whether B is statistically significant. (You have actually done that.) If one is and the other is not, you have a good argument for selecting one over the other. That would be related to using BIC but perhaps easier to understand.